# Find and delete lines containing multiple patterns in a file

Tags: sed, awk, grep, string

I have a list of strings and want to find and delete lines containing these strings in a file. A short example of the list of strings is listed as below.

File S

```
1Mo 32,33
2Mo 7,26
2Mo 7,27
2Mo 7,28
```

And a short example of the file is as follows.

File A

```
1Mo 32,33 I love you.
2Mo 7,26  I like you.
Hi 1,2  This is not so fun.
Ab 3,4  I am stupid.
```

My expected output is like this:

```
Hi 1,2  This is not so fun.
Ab 3,4  I am stupid.
```

I tried to use the following command, unfortunately I failed:

```
grep -f file S  file A|awk '{print $0}'
```

I searched the related question, but most of them focus on deleting the line with one specific pattern. I Does anybody know how to deal with this issue? Thx.

Comment: Try with `grep -vf file\ S  file\ A`

Comment: @don_crissti it works, many thx!!!

Comment: If there's any chance that your strings could contain a regular expression metacharacter, it is necessary to also use `-F`.

Answer (score 1):

In `AWK`, the code would be:

```
NR == FNR {
    line[$0]++;
    next;
}
!line[$1" "$2]
```

As an one liner:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {line[$0]++; next;} !line[$1" "$2]' file_S file_A
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -vF -f file_S file_A
Hi 1,2  This is not so fun.
Ab 3,4  I am stupid.
```

This uses the strings in `file_S` to get the lines in `file_A` that does not contain any of those strings.

`-v` inverts the sense of the matching so that lines without a match are passed through, and `-F` tells `grep` to treat the strings as *fixed string* and not like regular expressions.

Answer (score -3):

```
awk -F "|" '{if($1 != "1Mo") if($1 != "2Mo" ) { print $0;}}' inputFile > OutputFile
```

Comment: Snippet sharing for copy-paste is not a very HQ communication...

Comment: This answer could be made much more useful by [edit]ing it to explain in detail how it works.

Comment: You mean you're going to add a new `if`-statement for each line in the first file?